# Multiplication functional $M_f$ compact iff $f$ is in $c_0(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded function and let
$$
M_f : l^2(\mathbb{N}) \to l^2(\mathbb{N}) \hspace{0.2in} (M_fu)(n):=f(n)u(n)
$$
be the correspoding multiplication operator. Show that $M_f$ is compact iff $f$ is in $c_0(\mathbb{N}) = \{(a_n) \in l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})|a_n \to 0\}$

Another from my analaysis qual exam review sheet! Help is appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe use the fact that compact operators on Hilbert spaces are SOT limits of finite rank operators?

Comment: @David D.: Note that this is not a functional, but an operator.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that $M_f$ is an infinite diagonal matrix.

If $f\in c_0(\mathbb N)$, show that $M_f$ can be approximated by finite-rank operators. Hence, it is compact. Conversely, if $M_f$ is compact, it is firstly clear that $f\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ since $M_f$ is bounded. Now, the spectrum of $M_f$ consists of the $f(n)$ (only). These are the eigenvalues of $M_f$. Now, apply what you know about the spectrum of compact operators (I hope you do).

Comment: Not quite: the spectrum of $M_f$ also can contain accumulation points of the $f(n)$ that are not eigenvalues.  Of course, if $M_f$ is compact there can be only ...

Comment: But I assume here that $M_f$ is compact. So, such accumulation points (except zero) cannot exist.